# GLPK Simplex behavior with meth=GLP_PRIMAL vs meth=GLP_DUALP

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I have a linear program with no objective function. So I just want to test its feasibility. I am using GLPK api for simplex to do that. When I run simplex with the default method (meth=GLP_PRIMAL), the solver fails to converge in 100000 iterations (that is the limit I have set). However, when I use the method GLP_DUALP, after a few iterations I get the message "Warning: dual degeneracy; switching to primal simplex" and it goes on to converge in a reasonable number of iterations.

So my question is if it ultimately uses the primal simplex in both cases, why does it not converge in the first case. What might be going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is happening without detailed information about the problem, but basically the primal simplex in the case of dual degeneracy is some sort of "warm-started".

While using the dual algorithm the optimization process is generating a dual problem, which will start with an optimal solution and then tries to find a feasible solution which still contains the optimal condition. Primal simplex instead will start the other way around with a feasible solution and then search for an optimal solution.

When the strong duality theorem is true both optimal solution should be the same. In your Problem you get a "dual degeneracy" warning, which means that in the dual problem there is a equation which turns to be 0. So the variable inside this equation has no influence to the objective function (no matter if `X` is `100` or just `1`), this is plausible since you dont have an objective function. GLPK is then switching to primal simplex, because for the dual problem there exists alternative optimal solutions. With the already derived informations the primal simplex could be faster. I don't know what GLPK is exactly doing, but normally one can use the feasible solutions of the dual problem as a lower bound to the primal problem.

What stalls your primal approach is perhaps the same issue. The Problem degenerated and the simplex algorithm is getting stuck at one variable which has no influence to the objective, therefor it's hard to find an optimal value for this variable.